# Boundedness of supremum of an Integral operator

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, operator-theory

I am trying to find an $L_2$ - bound on a certain class of operators, and on my way I produced  an estimate for which I need to show that
\begin{equation}
\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \, \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{(1 + |x - y|)^{n+1}} \,dy 
\end{equation}
is finite. Here I am struggeling with the argument. What I understand is that the integral is finite, but how do I know that it is bounded as a function of $x$ ?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $\int f(y-x)\,dy = \int f(y)\,dy$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.